# How can I show that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}=0$ by $\varepsilon, \delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I have to show that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=0$$ by $\epsilon, \delta$

So far, I only have that: Given $\epsilon>0$ such that $|\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}-0|<\epsilon$ then  $\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{|x|}<\epsilon$. But I can't solve for $| x-0 |$ of this expression to obtain a suitable $\delta$

Any one has a hint?

$\textbf{Upgrade}:$

Note that $$|\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}| \leq \frac{\frac{1}{1/x^2}}{|x|}=\frac{x^2}{|x|}=\frac{|x||x|}{|x|}=|x|$$

Then, if $\epsilon >0$ is such that $\epsilon > |x|$. Taking $\delta=\epsilon$ we have that if $|x-0|\leq\delta$ then $|\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}-0| \leq \epsilon$

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you have access to any inequalities involving the exponential function? For example, $\exp(-1/x^2)\leq x^2$ for all $x\neq 0$, etc.

Comment: Yes, I have @user429040

Comment: Can you construct an $\epsilon, \delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = 0$?

Comment: As a rule, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0 \iff \lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = 0.$  That is, $f(x)$ approaches $0$ if and only if $|f(x)|$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Letting $y=1/x,$ compute: $$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{y}{e^{y^2}}$$ and likewise for $y\to-\infty.$ (But the second limit follows from the first.)

Comment: And note $e^{y^2}>y^2.$

Comment: e^-(infinity)=0.

Comment: e^-(infinity)=0, but then we get 0/0 an indeterminate form. So why not put x in the numerator? e^(-1/x^2)/e^log(x)=e^(-1/x^2-logx).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{x\,\to\,0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}} x = \lim_{u\,\to\,\pm\infty} \frac u {e^{u^2}} \quad \text{(where $u = \dfrac 1 x$)} 
$$

When $u$ is big (imagine $u=1\,000\,000$ or more?) then when $u$ is incremented by $1,$ then $u^2$ increases by more than $2u$ (more than $2\,000\,000$ in the foregoing example) so $e^{u^2}$ gets multiplied by more than $e^{2u}$ (more than $e^{4\,000\,000}$ in that example). Thus at every such step, the fraction becomes a tiny fraction of what it was before the incrementing of $u.$

Comment: I understand the change of variable and how it is that $e^{u^2}$ grows faster than $u$. But how does this help me to show that the limit is $0$ by $\epsilon, \delta$?